# randomising layout with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

I have 10 elements all with the class `.item` what I am wanting to do is shuffle those elements into a new order, and then assign a further class to them.

What I am trying to achieve is layout where by an element can span `33.33333333%` or `66.66666666%` (i.e 1/3 or 2/3). The problem comes in that there are a number of rules to be adhered too.

There are 3 setups for a row,

```
1) 3 X 1/3
2) 1 x 1/3 + 1 x 2/3
3) 1 x 2/3 + 1 x 1/3
```

Now I cannot work out how to assign classes to my elements to maintain theses rules, I dont care what order the rules are adered too, aslong there is never 2 x 2/3 on the same row.

So far I have managed to shuffle my elements into a random (objective 1 complete).  Thanks to another Stackoverflow post,

```
jQuery.fn.shuffle = function () {
        var j;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
            $(this[i]).before($(this[j]));
        }
        return this;
    };
```

But i have no idea how I would go about adding the other classes I need (`.item__w-1` or `.item-w-2`) and adhere to the rules of making sure that the elements on a row always add up to 3/3.

Comment: Do you want those classes random too, or the information about preferred width is stored somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.shuffle = function () {
    var getRandomInt = function (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };

    var l = this.length;
    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < l; i++) {
        j = getRandomInt(0, l);

        $(this[i]).before($(this[j]));
    }

    var reloaded = $(this.selector);
    for (i = 0, weight = 0, currentWeight = 1; i != l; ++i) {
        currentWeight = 1 + getRandomInt(0, 2 - weight);

        $(reloaded[i]).addClass('item__w-' + currentWeight);

        weight = weight + currentWeight < 3 ? weight + currentWeight : 0;
    }

    return this;
};
```

I assumed you wanted random classes order too. How does it work: after shuffling your items, iterate over them once more. Select random class from 1 - 3 range (you can change it to whatever maximum you want, so 2 if you don't want full-weight element). Make sure that there are always items which sum to total of 3.

http://jsfiddle.net/Misiur/QCjvR/

Comment: This looks great! I assume I use like `$(".item").shuffle()`

Comment: Oh sorry, I've tested in in jsfiddle and it doesn't work as it should yet (the shuffling shenanigans don't affect this, and the classes are misassigned). I'll get back to you in 10 minutes

Comment: Got it! Added jsfiddle